# Javascript add litteral every 4th index

Tags: javascript

How can i add a character every 4th litteral inside test:

```
var test = "329923448238";
```

So test will be:

```
3299-2344-8238
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regex to match and replace every group of four characters and append with a dash.

```
test.replace(/(.{4})(?!$)/g, '$1-');
```

That regex matches and captures any character four times, except if it's immediately followed by the end of the string (in which case you don't want a dash).

Check out this [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/wuobhjLw/)

Comment: smart answer. write a article on regex.